# MOXy/JAXB interface annotation

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I have a model that consists of an interface with one annotated property, and a concrete implementor that does not re-annotate the implementation of that property.  Why doesn't this unmarshal correctly (using MOXy 2.5.0)?  I get a correctly constructed object, but the property is never bound to the XML:

```xml
<!-- XML -->
<InterfaceImpl id="5150" />
```

```java
/**
 * Annotated interface
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="IInterface")
public interface IInterface
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public void setId(int id);
}

/**
 * Concrete implementor
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="InterfaceImpl")
public class InterfaceImpl implements IInterface
{
    private int m_id = -1;

    @Override
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        m_id = id;
    }   
}

/**
 * Unmarshal code
 */
File f = new File("src\\resources\\Interface.xml");
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MY_PATH);
Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
InterfaceImpl i = (InterfaceImpl)u.unmarshal(f);
```

If I change IInterface to an abstract class, it works correctly - shouldn't abstract classes and interfaces be handled the same way?  Is this expected behavior, or a known issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**oxm.xml**

You could use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy's) external binding file to make MOXy think that `IInterface` is the super class of `InterfaceImpl` instead of `Object`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16878949">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="InterfaceImpl" super-type="forum16878949.IInterface"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

Below is how you can specify the mapping document when creating the `JAXBContext`.  For the purpose of this demo I added a `getId` method to `InterfaceImpl` so I could show the unmarshalling worked.

```java
package forum16878949;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    private static String MY_PATH = "forum16878949";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /**
         * Unmarshal code
         */
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum16878949/oxm.xml");
        File f = new File("src/forum16878949/Interface.xml");
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MY_PATH, IInterface.class.getClassLoader(), properties);
        Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
        InterfaceImpl i = (InterfaceImpl)u.unmarshal(f);
        System.out.println(i.getId());
    }

}
```

**Interface.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InterfaceImpl id="123"/>
```

**Output**

```
123
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties

Comment: Thanks for your response, Blaise - you were the guy I wanted to hear from. :)  So it sounds like I should not expect this to work the way I want it to, i.e. there is no way to unmarshal a class that implements an annotated interface without knowing the specific type in advance.

Comment: I have to say that I'm still not clear why an interface doesn't behave the same as an abstract class, I understand that they are semantically "different" from the JVM's perspective, but I don't see why JAXB has to treat them any differently.  Could you provide some insight into the unmarshalling algorithm that might highlight why this isn't technologically feasible?

Comment: @StephenCarlson - I have figured out a way to support your use case.  I have redone my answer with a complete example.

Comment: This is great, and I'll accept it as the correct answer, although I'd still like a little more insight into the unmarshalling process that would explain why interfaces are treated differently than abstract classes.  If I can declare a variable with an interface type, I ought to be able to declare an annotated property with one too.  Shouldn't I?