# Moxy JAXB and Interfaces

Tags: jaxb, moxy

There has been quite some discussion on how to user Moxy and JaxB Interfaces

see e.g.

- [MOXy/JAXB interface annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878949/moxy-jaxb-interface-annotation/16903047#16903047)
- [MOXy/JAXB "prototype pattern" - interface inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807019/moxy-jaxb-prototype-pattern-interface-inheritance)

The answers by Blaise Doughan have partly been accepted and partly not.
I have tried to adapt the answers in

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest

see the

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/jaxb/TestJaxbFactory.java

test case. At the time being there is an

```
@Ignore
```

added to the testcase. If i uncomment the @Ignore I get different errors depending which unmarshalling approach I try:

**1. Using an xml META description the error is:**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element UserManager was not found in the project]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:214)
    at com.bitplan.jaxb.TestJaxbFactory.unmarshalFromContext(TestJaxbFactory.java:166)
    at com.bitplan.jaxb.TestJaxbFactory.testUserManager(TestJaxbFactory.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
```

**2. using the ObjectFactory approach I get:**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-44] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl@38c6f217].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.bitplan.rest.users.User --> [])]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:225)
    at com.bitplan.jaxb.TestJaxbFactory.unmarshalFromContext(TestJaxbFactory.java:166)
    at com.bitplan.jaxb.TestJaxbFactory.testUserManager(TestJaxbFactory.java:215)
```

**3. Using the JaxbFactory approach that works for Customer/Order i get:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.bitplan.rest.users.User
    at com.bitplan.jaxb.TestJaxbFactory.testUserManager(TestJaxbFactory.java:219)
```

**How would I get this to work?**

**Which of the three approaches are ok and Moxy is just buggy or there is an error in the approaches?**

**Testcode**

```java
  @Test
  @Ignore
  public void testUnMarshalViaMetaXML() throws Exception {
    String xml = getUserManagerXml();
    String metaxml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
        + "<xml-bindings\n"
        + "    xmlns=\"http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm\"\n"
        + "    package-name=\"com.bitplan.rest.users\">\n"
        + "    <xml-schema\n"
        + "        namespace=\"http://www.example.com/user\"\n"
        + "        element-form-default=\"QUALIFIED\"/>\n"
        + "    <java-types>\n"
        + "            <java-type name=\"UserManagerImpl\">\n"
        + "            <xml-root-element name=\"UserManager\"/>\n"
        + "            <java-attributes>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"users\">\n"
        + "                   <xml-element-wrapper name=\"users\"/>\n"
        + "                </xml-element>\n"
        + "            </java-attributes>\n"
        + "        </java-type>\n"
        + "        <java-type name=\"UserImpl\">\n"
        + "            <xml-root-element name=\"User\"/>\n"
        + "            <xml-type prop-order=\"id name firstname email password comment \"/>\n"
        + "            <java-attributes>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"name\" name=\"name\"/>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"firstName\" name=\"firstName\"/>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"email\" name=\"email\"/>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"password\" name=\"password\"/>\n"
        + "                <xml-element java-attribute=\"comment\" name=\"comment\"/>\n"
        + "            </java-attributes>\n" + "        </java-type>\n"
        + "    </java-types>\n" + "</xml-bindings>";
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = JaxbFactory.createJAXBContext(
        "com.bitplan.rest.users", metaxml);
    UserManager um4 = unmarshalFromContext(jaxbContext, xml);
    assertNotNull(um4);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Test
  @Ignore
  public void testUnmarshalViaObjectFactory() throws Exception {
    String xml = getUserManagerXml();
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Class[] classes = { ObjectFactory.class };
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(
        classes, properties);
    UserManager um3 = unmarshalFromContext(jaxbContext, xml);
    assertNotNull(um3);
  }

  @Test
  @Ignore
  public void testUnmarshalViaFromXml() throws Exception {
    String xml = getUserManagerXml();
    UserManager um2 = UserManagerImpl.fromXml(xml);
    assertEquals(2, um2.getUsers().size());
    for (User user : um2.getUsers()) {
      System.out.println(user.getId());
    }
    User jd = um2.getById("jd001");
    jd.deCrypt(um2.getCrypt());
    assertEquals("badpassword", jd.getPassword());
  }
```

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, were you able to make it work?

Comment: no  - this was a night mare when i was still using Java. I am now using python and the tooling there is way better. I am also preferring proper graph structures to hierarchical ones. If i am forced I'll use json but graphml and gremlin is way better. The bad news is that there is no native gremlin for python it's still java based.

Comment: see https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/SimpleGraph for how things are much simpler with gremlin the https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/SimpleGraph-XML is a prototype